# Simple category-entry search filter

Tags: entries, categories, frontend, sorting

I'm trying to figure what would be the simplest way to do such filtering:

I would like to make it in that way that selecting one of "Specialities" category would limit results from the selected "Plant" category.

Though I want a selection of the second category to be optional, so everyone can browse live and dried i.e. Mint plants or only herbs from all plants if they want.

Also, I would like to implement shipping to/from drop-downs with the same functionality.

Expected result:
[image: ![enter image description here]

How can I start? Any help would be greatly appreciated :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article was helpful getting us started when we tackled an advanced search. Though their example uses dropdowns, you'll probably want to use checkboxes for your "Herbs" and "Live Plants" categories.

[Combined searches and filters](https://www.webstoemp.com/blog/combined-searches-and-filters-craft-cms/)